# Gearman queue and symfony2: jobs aren't supposed to be queued?

Tags: multithreading, symfony, gearman

I have really a two big questions:

Scenario: I have a process that performs video processing. And I have one worker. I implemented gearman with symfony2 with gearbundle(mmoreram)

- I send this backgroundJob that takes 3 minutes. I have to send it everytime is requested(user uploads a video). The problem is that first whom have requested is processed. While this is working, and receive more requested, these others should be waiting on the queue, right? And when the worker is free, should enter the next on the queue right? But... why the others never arrive to the worker. What could be happened? May missing something? Gearman is task queue right?
- And this is personal: Why a worker needs iterations? Iterations means that end to work when has processed n-iterations. Why should I want to kill my workers?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Once the job is completed by the worker, next Job should be processed. This is how typically the Gearman works and is supposed to work.

As you are saying that the next jobs are not processed, then there must be some issue with your worker code. Would be good if you can elaborate your question with some more explanation as what you are trying to do, with some sample code.
It would be good, if you enable the logging from your worker code so that you know what's happening.

You should even try using the Geaman Monitoring tools which will help you know the number of jobs scheduled, processed, failed etc. Some of the references for your are

- GearmanUI - http://gaspaio.github.io/gearmanui/
- Monitoring over Telnet - http://preilly.me/2009/08/06/monitoring-gearman-over-telnet-port-4730/
- Gearman Monitor - https://github.com/yugene/Gearman-Monitor

Regarding your 2nd Question, there is no need to kill workers after completing N number of jobs.